# Fill na column of 2nd dataframe with 1st dataframe which are matching in R

Tags: r

```
DF1 = data.frame(A=c("cats","dogs","pig"), B=c("kittens","puppies","pig"),C=c("dog","cat","mouse"))

DF2 = data.frame( A=c("cats","dogs","pig"), B=c("kittens",NA,NA))
```

The 2nd DF2 has NA column but i need to replace NA with pig row of 1st column. It should match the row of NA with the row of DF1 and replace accordingly. I have tried with merge but it doesn't work.

Comment: Check `rows_update` from package `dplyr`.

Comment: Please don't provide your data as image. Please use `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` to copy the data here.

Comment: Okay. I will change it

Comment: This? `replace(DF2$B, is.na(DF2$B), DF1$B[match(DF1$A, DF2$A)][is.na(DF2$B)])`

Comment: Are you still planning to share the data?

Comment: Yes. I will do it now

Comment: just changed the data .Error: Attempting to update missing rows.

Comment: "Yes. I will do it now", I still don't see the data updated in your post.

Comment: I am sorry but your solution worked on the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
DF2 |> 
  rows_update(DF1, by = "A")

     A       B
1 cats kittens
2 dogs puppies
3  pig     pig
```

---

UPDATE: a solution in case the joining data frames have different columns:

```
DF1 <- tibble(A = c("cats","dogs","pig"),
              B = c("kittens","puppies","pig"),
              C = c(1:3))

DF2 <- data.frame(A = c("cats","dogs","pig"),
                  B = c("kittens","puppies",NA))

DF2 |> 
  rows_update(DF1 |> select(any_of(names(DF2))),
              by = "A")
```

Comment: This is fine for even dataframe. But if there are more columns it showsAll columns in `y` must exist in `x`.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: I am not able to do on my csv. I have attached the csv  now and it's throwing same error. 

a<- read.csv2("df1.csv")
b<-read.csv2("df2.csv")
x<-data.frame(a)
y<-data.frame(b)

library(dplyr)
x |> 
  rows_update(y |> select(any_of(names(x))),
              by = "VARCODE")

Comment: I have updated my question with the image. Can you please have a look